# is it a memory leak in fragment onAttach using mActivity = context?

Tags: android

I use a mActivity for maintaining a context of activity.

*onAttach*

```
    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        if(context is Activity) mActivity  = context
    }
```

I thought If I use this, it would be a memory leak because mActivity maintain the activity reference, and when the activity is destroyed, the mActivity is still referencing the activity that is destroyed.
is it good way to use mActivity?

Comment: to avoid a memory leak you could set the `mActivity` to null on detach

Comment: I know that way, but if I want to use the context after activity is destroyed, I can't use that way. like this`Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        showToast(mActivity!!,"activity!!")
    },5000) // after activity is destroyed`, this will occur error.

Comment: personally i see no need to keep a reference to context when there are better ways of getting it

Comment: If it's a `Fragment` then you should use the already existing `getActivity()`. Yes it would return `null` after it being detached, and you shouldn't not use the detached `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use activity as context to message. you should add `mHandler.removeCallback` or `mHandler.removeMessages` on detached.

---

It seems that this operation is feasible.
But what you need to know is that the memory leak is because an object with a longer life cycle (singleton ..) holds a reference to an object with a shorter life cycle (Activity or Fragment).

```
if(getActivity() != null){...}
// when you use getActivity()=, you need a NPE check.
```

if you use `mActivity = getAcitvity`. You can use `mActivity` as context all the time. MaenWihle the fragment hold the activity after fragement detached. you might set `mActivity` to null in `onDetached` method. Then you should need another NPE check.

```
if(mActivity != null){...}
// when you use mActivity, you also need a NPE check.
```